# Postgres query on relations

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query:

```
@profiles = Profile.where('whatami LIKE ? AND expectedsalaray <= ?', '%' + @job.title + '%', @job.salary)
```

Profiles is associated with another model called cities `profile.cites`
How can i check this associated model in the where statement ?

so something like:

```
Profile.where('profiles.city LIKE ?', @job.city)
```

Here are my associations:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
end
```

Comment: Does profile `belongs_to` city?

Comment: Can you update your question and include your models for the two tables? We just need the relation info. `has_one`, `has_many`, `belongs_to`.

Comment: iv updated my question with the associations

Comment: I'm not sure `has_and_belongs_to_many` is the correct association for what you are trying to accomplish. I also don't know anything except what you've posted so I might be missing something. Do you have a table called `cities_profiles` that has `city_id` and `profile_id`? That's usually required for this type of relationship. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a crack at answering this with the assumption your models have declared their associations correctly.

```
class Profile
  belongs_to :city
end

class City
  has_many :profiles
end

@profiles = Profile.where('whatami ILIKE ? AND expectedsalaray <= ? AND
cities.name ILIKE ?', "%#{@job.title}%", @job.salary, "%#{@job.city}%").joins(:city)
```

`.joins()` will add a left join to your SQL/Postgres allowing you to reference columns from the joined table.

I've added interpolation to your like wildcard to make it a little shorter vs. all the plus signs.

Using `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` can help prevent problems related to case sensitivity. Thanks to @Shayna for reminding me of that.

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Association named 'city' was not found on Profile; perhaps you misspelled it?' Iv updated my question with the associations

Comment: Or instead of converting everything to the same case you can use ILIKE for case-insensitive matching.